# Move files into sub-subfolders based on their file name, for multiple subfolders

Tags: mv, for

I have 100+ subfolders (`P_XXX`), each containing three sets of files (`run1`, `run2` and `run3`):

```
/Analysis   
  /P_076
      /run1
      /run2
      /run3
      swu_run1_P_076_vol_001.nii
      swu_run1_P_076_vol_002.nii
      swu_run2_P_076_vol_001.nii
      swu_run2_P_076_vol_002.nii
      swu_run3_P_076_vol_001.nii
      swu_run3_P_076_vol_002.nii   
   /P_102
      /run1
      /run2
      /run3
      swu_run1_P_102_vol_001.nii
      swu_run1_P_102_vol_002.nii
      swu_run2_P_102_vol_001.nii
      swu_run2_P_102_vol_002.nii
      swu_run3_P_102_vol_001.nii
      swu_run3_P_102_vol_002.nii
```

I would like to move the three sets of files to its own subfolders (run1, run2 and run3) within the existing subfolder:

```
/Analysis
  /P_076
     /run1 
        swu_run1_P_076_vol_001.nii
        swu_run1_P_076_vol_002.nii
     /run2
        swu_run2_P_076_vol_001.nii
        swu_run2_P_076_vol_002.nii
     /run3
        swu_run3_P_076_vol_001.nii
        swu_run3_P_076_vol_002.nii
  /P_102
     /run1
        swu_run1_P_102_vol_001.nii
        swu_run1_P_102_vol_002.nii
      /run2 
        swu_run2_P_102_vol_001.nii
        swu_run2_P_102_vol_002.nii
      /run3
        swu_run3_P_102_vol_001.nii
        swu_run3_P_102_vol_002.nii
```

The below code does the trick when I run the script within the subfolder (P_XXX):

```
for f in swu_run?_*.nii; do
       num=${f:7:1}
       mv "$f" run"$num"/
    
done'
```

But I am struggling to find the appropriate `for` loop to make it work from the parent directory (Analysis), rather than manually running it within each subfolder. I tried the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*.nii' -exec bash -c '
for f in swu_run?_*.nii; do
     num=${f:7:1}
     mv "$f" run"$num"/
 
done' bash {} +
```

This returns the error message `cannot stat 'swu_run?_*.nii': No such file or directory.`

How do I run the code at the level of the Analysis folder, so that each P_XXX subfolder is reorganised in three further subfolders (run1, run2 and run3) with their matching files in one go?

Comment: The `bash -c` script in your `find` command already gets a number of pathnames to files with names ending in `.nii`.  You should not need to expand any filename globbing pattern in that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two loops with `bash`:

```
cd /path/to/Analysis
shopt -s nullglob
for i in {1..3}; do
  for f in */swu_run${i}_*.nii; do
     mv "$f" "${f%/*}/run${i}/"
  done
done
```

The enabled `nullglob` shell option makes sure that the inner loop is not entered if `*/swu_run${i}_*.nii` doesn't match any files (already moved or missing).

The parameter expansion `${f%/*}` removes the shortest suffix pattern `/*` leaving the path of the parent directory.